# Moving a partition to the end of disk using gparted

Tags: partitioning, windows, gparted, windows-10

I'm planning to use gparted to move a(the?) OEM partition created by win 10 to the end of the disk. The disk looks like:

[image: win 10 disk partitions]

Can the OEM partition be safely moved to the end of the disk?

I tried it earlier with gparted and there were gaps of unallocated space in between the OS(C:) partition and the newly moved free partition at the end. Can these spaces be used so that the OS partition is contiguous up until the start of the OEM partition?

Comment: The windows default partitioning (Disk Management) tool does not allow for moving partitions (only extending partitions (to the right) provided there is sufficient space to do so).

Comment: With my Dell when I did a Dell backup, it asked if I wanted to remove the Dell recovery partition. And after Windows backup it asked if I wanted to remove that partition. And I still did a full Windows backup with Macrium. Order of partitions on a drive is not critical.

Answer (score 0):

Run gparted from ubuntu usb, or other disk(if you have it)

- Make backup of important files
- Move OEM partition to the end, then you'll have unallocated space on
  right of C: partition
- Make C: partition larger, using that unallocated space

Comment: In gparted I also have a space that seems "unallocateable" in between the unallocated space and the OS partition

Comment: Have you moved OEM partition, and still have "unallocateble"? Include gparted screenshot in question.

Comment: Try to move OEM with gparted and extend C using windows tool.

Comment: Another way: Create a second OEM at the end copies over the files and then remove the old oem

Answer (score 0):

[You can as well safely delete the OEM partition.](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/delete-oem-partition.html#:%7E:text=OEM%20partitions%20are%20created%20by,without%20causing%20any%20PC%20issue.) "If you have the Windows installation CD or Windows creation media, you can also get to the same recovery features by simply booting off a Windows 10 CD or memory stick." You can delete the OEM partition. From the snapshot, I can say the deleted OEM partition will add to the Unallocated partition and you can create a new partition from this unallocated partition. Right click on the Unallocated space and the options to do so should appear.

Moving the OEM partitions concerned, I think you will be able to move to then end once you create new partition/partitions from the unallocated part. I can't tell if windows will be able to use this moved OEM partition for restoration operations.